# Rails: method works in a for loop, not outside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, loops

This may take some explanation so do bear with me.

I'm trying to access an image in Rails stored with Paperclip. The images can be accessed perfectly in a `for` loop, thus:

```
for a in @issue.articles
  image_tag a.image.url
end
```

Do note that `@issue` has no articles method; I'm not sure why that works. It does, however, have `article1`, `article2`, and `article3`; and each of those has the image in question.

If I try to access the image outside the loop with this code it fails, thus:

```
image_tag @issue.article1.image.url
```

Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: The articles method comes from your issue association. Can you post your code for the article1/2/3 methods?

Comment: They're columns in a database. I didn't know what else to call them in explaining this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct way is

```
@issue.articles.first.image.url
```

or for each of them

```
@issue.articles[0].image.url
@issue.articles[1].image.url
@issue.articles[2].image.url
```